# ASP.NET MVC Models in Seperate Project, not able to select to use Model Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First serious attempt at getting into MVC. Understand the principles (so I think).

I've created a fairly simple application using Fluent NHibernate for my Data Access and have abstracted it with Service Layer above that. My entities are in my Domain and I have a few other projects as below.

```
MyApp (error reporting & constants)
MyApp.DataAccess (FNH)
MyApp.Domain (entities)
MyApp.Interfaces
MyApp.ServiceLayer
MyApp.Utils
MyApp.Web
```

I have just added these projects to a new MVC solution, and when attempting to create a View based on a simple Controller, I don't get any options for which Model class to use.

[image]

I figure this may be something to do with the namespace of the classes I wish to use for my Models (MyApp.Domain), but not sure how to go about pulling them in? I have a reference to the DLL in my MVC project and everything compiles fine.

Comment: Do you mean don't get the option in the scaffolding wizard? or When typing the class name in the view? I think you will need to pull in the model assembly via a 'using' in the view. Or use the fully qualified MyApp.Domain.Class when referring to them

Comment: Does it work if you create an empty view and specify the model manually?

Comment: If I specify the Model manually it works fine. I guess I can just forget using the wizard, it's not a massive deal.

Comment: It should work using the wizard, did you compile the project yet?

Comment: Yeah I think the scaffolding templates may only interrogate the current assembly. 
What you could do I'd suggest is creating 'ViewModels' in your .Web application and returning those to your views.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald This isn't the case, the wizard can pull in models from any referenced assembly.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to think back to the last time I used the scaffolding, which was a while back! the viewmodels comment may be valid however.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Partially, though you would likely want your view models in an external project too :)

Comment: So ViewModel is like an implementation of my Domain Models that is specifically used for interacting with my Views? Where can I read up on all this, I feel like I've gone in at the deep end!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they are, it keeps the data layer completely separated from the view. You can use tools like Automapper to create one from the other too. I wouldn't worry about it for now if this is your first MVC application. You're doing great so far!

Comment: The asp.net MVC site is a great start point. MS in it's templates (and tutorials will refer to view models as 'Models') as per this page - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-model - but they mean view models!